# How to display a value in my title attribute

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Is there a way to add a value into my title attribute inside my Dropdown tag. For example I want to get title='Lead' + {this.state.candidate.length}. I am also using Dropdown from 'rsuite'.

```
<Sidenav className="nav1-full" defaultOpenKeys={['1']} activeKey="1">
  <Sidenav.Body>
    <Nav className="nav-bar">
      <Dropdown className="nav1-body" eventKey="1" title="Lead">
        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1-1" href="/candidates/1">
          Exploratory
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1-2" href="/candidates/2">
          Phone Intro
        </Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Sidenav.Body>
</Sidenav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since anything inside {} is an inline JSX expression, you can do:

```
 title={"Lead" + this.state.candidate.length}
```

You can also use ES6 string interpolation/template literals with `` (backticks) and `${expr}` , like this:

```
 title={`Lead${this.state.candidate.length}`}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your prop in brackets *{}* instead of quotes

In the brackets you can write any javascript code:

```
<Dropdown title={'Lead ' + this.state.candidate.length}>
```

ES6 way:

```
<Dropdown title={`Lead${his.state.candidate.length}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   title={`Lead${this.state.candidate.length}`}
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Simple `template string` solution.

```
 title={`WhateverYouWantHere`}
```